# How to stop Firefox opening xml files and get gedit to open them instead

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, gedit

When ever I open an xml file in Ubuntu it opens with Firefox, how do I change the file association to open with gedit instead?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change this way

1. Right click on a xml  file
2. Choose "Properties"
3. Click on the "Open With" tab
4. Choose your new default  editor

If you still face the issue Please have look on this page : http://linuxfud.wordpress.com/2006/09/03/ubuntu-linux-file-associations/

**(or )**

Change the default "Open with" program for a file type

- In Nautilus, right click on the file and choose Properties from the menu that appears. The Properties dialog opens.
- Click on the Open With tab. A list of applications appears.
- Select the default application you want for the file type. If the application is not on the list, use the Add button to add the application to the list.

Comment: source on the second half of your post, please

Comment: The second method worked for me in Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 0):

open the defaults.list file

```
sudo subl /usr/share/applications/defaults.list
```

and search for the xml extension:

```
text/xml=firefox.desktop
```

and replace it for example for the sublime text editor or your choice

```
text/xml=sublime_text.desktop
```

Enjoy!